# Error trying to replace the words "VERDADERO" or "FALSO" in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have a table.

| header1 | header2 |
| --- | --- |
| xxxx | VERDADERO |
| VERDADERO | VERDADERO |
| xxxx | xxxx |
| VERDADERO | xxxx |
| VERDADERO | xxxx |

I'm using the Spanish version of Excel.

```vb
Sub replace()
Dim sheet_name, table_name As String

sheet_name= InputBox("enter the sheet name", "Input")
table_name = InputBox("enter the table name", "Input")

With Worksheets(sheet_name).ListObjects(table_name )
    .ListColumns("header1").DataBodyRange.Replace _
      What:="VERDADERO", Replacement:="USE LVL 2", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
    
    .ListColumns("header2").DataBodyRange.Replace _
      What:="VERDADERO", Replacement:="USE LVL 1", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End With

End Sub
```

When I try to replace the words "VERDADERO" or "FALSO" it does not make any changes.

Those two words mean "true" and "false", but they don't have any apostrophes at the beginning of the cell. I also tried changing the format to Text.

Comment: Am I right that those two words mean "false" and "true" - those are special words in Excel as in `1=1=TRUE`. Check if they have an apostrophe at the beginning of the cell - to be displayed as text.

Comment: Yes, those two words mean "false" and "true", but they don't have any apostrophes at the beginning of the cell. I also tried changing the format to Text

Comment: `VERDADERO` (same as `TRUE` in the Spanish Excel) and `FALSO` (=`FALSE`) are not strings. _Applying_ Text format _after_ it's been entered in the cell does not change its kind (same for a number). The apostrophe before does change it to strings; if the format is Text, just editing the cell (F2+Enter) will do the same; but you need to edit the cell after applying the format.

Comment: Please, try `.ListColumns("header1").DataBodyRange.Replace _
 What:=VERDADERO, Replacement:="USE LVL 2", _
 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns`. Without double quotes (`Boolean`). If it does not work, try replacing it with `What:=True`...

Comment: Then replace `What:="VERDADERO"` with `What:=True` .  VBA expects English

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next more compact way. No need to change format to text:

```
Sub replace()
Dim sheet_name, table_name As String, ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject

sheet_name = InputBox("enter the sheet name", "Input")
table_name = InputBox("enter the table name", "Input")

Set ws = Worksheets(sheet_name)
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(table_name)

 ws.Range(tbl & "[[header1]:[header2]]").replace VERDADERO, "USE LVL 2", xlWhole
 'if the above code does not work (I cannot test), comment it and uncomment the next  line:
 'ws.Range(tbl & "[[header1]:[header2]]").replace True, "USE LVL 2", xlWhole

End Sub
```

Comment: THANKS!! the solution was just as  
chris neilsen said. Replacing What:="VERDADERO" with What:=True or What:="FALSO" with What:=False

Comment: @danny I wrote that **3 minutes before his comment**? See the comments order,  please... And I tried making the code more compact, not replacing in consecutive steps, per each column.